# Possible to do a SUM IF equivalent in TSQL where the condition is not constant?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, aggregate, ssms

I have data available for licenses used and max licenses available every 10 minutes, I'd like to aggregate by day, and need to know the count of license maxouts (used licenses = total licenses) for each day. I've seen plenty of conditionals where a column is equal to a constant, but can't find anything for a condition where one column is equal to another column. I can't hard code the maximum licenses because this needs to work for thousands of different software packages, and theoretically the same package could have a different number of max licenses in a given time period. Please help!

Here's what I have so far, I know the 3rd line in the SELECT statement is wrong but don't know what to use instead.

```
DECLARE @unixTimeStamp INT = 1495571176;
DECLARE @featValue INT = 877;
DECLARE @unixMark INT = @unixTimeStamp - 2629746;

SELECT 
    FORMAT(DATEADD(S, StampedUnixTime, '1970-01-01'), 'MM/dd') AS Date
    COUNT(*) FILTER WHERE UsedLicenses = TotalLicenses AS Maxouts,
    MAX(FH.UsedLicenses) AS UsedLicenses, 
    MAX(FH.TotalLicenses) AS TotalLicenses
FROM Feature_History as FH 
WHERE ([FeatureID] = @featValue) AND (FH.StampedUnixTime BETWEEN @unixMark AND @unixTimeStamp)
GROUP BY FORMAT(DATEADD(S, StampedUnixTime, '1970-01-01'), 'MM/dd')
ORDER BY Date
```

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is a conditional aggregation.

```
DECLARE @unixTimeStamp INT = 1495571176;
DECLARE @featValue INT = 877;
DECLARE @unixMark INT = @unixTimeStamp - 2629746;

SELECT 
    FORMAT(DATEADD(S, StampedUnixTime, '1970-01-01'), 'MM/dd') AS Date,
    sum(case when UsedLicenses = TotalLicenses then 1 else 0 end) as MaxOuts,
    MAX(FH.UsedLicenses) AS UsedLicenses, 
    MAX(FH.TotalLicenses) AS TotalLicenses
FROM Feature_History as FH 
WHERE ([FeatureID] = @featValue) AND (FH.StampedUnixTime BETWEEN @unixMark AND @unixTimeStamp)
GROUP BY FORMAT(DATEADD(S, StampedUnixTime, '1970-01-01'), 'MM/dd')
ORDER BY Date
```